# Locate Text of widget

Tags: php, wordpress

I got problem when I migrate my blog from one server to another. I had a side widget with a descriptive text which I liked. Now it is gone, and I can't find it among the files I backed up before migrating the blog. So, how can I find the text among tons of files? I've been trying the computer search engine with key-words without success.

Comment: please include some code, or at least a sample of the widget element html, or a site link, or just a little more information about what this text did or where it came from.

Comment: Widget configuration is typically stored in the database. That said, this might get a better answer at [wordpress.se].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Widget data is serialized, and stored in the WordPress options table (`wp_options` by default). The option names are prefixed with `widget_`, e.g. `widget_text`, `widget_recent-posts`, etc.